# display posts from specific category on a page , in thematic child theme?

Tags: categories, page-template

i have a blog page template , i need to make it display posts from specific category called news 
this is the template , i use thematic framework child theme

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Blog
*
* This template allows you to display the latest posts on any page of the site.
*
*/

    // calling the header.php
    get_header();

    // action hook for placing content above #container
    thematic_abovecontainer();

?>

<div id="container">
<?php thematic_abovecontent(); ?>
<div id="content">
<?php
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( array( 'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), 'paged' => $paged ) );
$more = 0;
?>

<?php

             // create the navigation above the content
             thematic_navigation_above();

             // calling the widget area 'index-top'
             get_sidebar('index-top');

             // action hook for placing content above the index loop
             thematic_above_indexloop();

             // action hook creating the index loop
             thematic_indexloop();

             // action hook for placing content below the index loop
             thematic_below_indexloop();

             // calling the widget area 'index-bottom'
             get_sidebar('index-bottom');

             // create the navigation below the content
             thematic_navigation_below();

             ?>
</div><!-- #content -->
<?php thematic_belowcontent(); ?>
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php

    // action hook for placing content below #container
    thematic_belowcontainer();

    // calling the standard sidebar
    /*thematic_sidebar();*/

    // calling footer.php
    get_footer();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing :

```
$wp_query->query( array( 'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

to

```
$wp_query->query( array( 'category_name' => 'news','posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

You need to use slug, in this example "news" is the slug of the category.